# IIS Website cannot access network share with the SAME app pool that is used by default website which does work

Tags: iis, application-pool, remote-server, network-share, network-service

We have a production application (Classic ASP, IIS 7.5) that uses the IIS Default Website and a virtual directory. The application accesses documents from a document share. It works and has worked for many years.

Recently we have added a number of new web applications all under Default Web Site and we are attempting to separate them out into their own IIS Websites. So, we setup a new IIS Website and used a binding to get the application to use the new web site and used the same application pool pointing to the exact same code. (note: our application uses subdomains to point to different databases so we just took one subdomain and binded it to the new site).

For some reason, the documents that are accessible from the Default Web Site are not accessible in the new website. But given that both are using the same application pool and thus share the same application pool identity, how is it possible that one website can access the share, but the other cannot?

More info. we have tried using a domain user as the app pool identity and NETWORKSERVICE both of which work in the Default, neither of which work in the new web site. Also, how are we accessing the documents? We have an ASP file which simply uses the ADO Stream object and we reference the file using "\\docserver\documents..." (which again, is the same in both websites as they are both looking at the same code.